# Rails - Creating many models in one form - in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a small question - how can I create many models and save it to a database throught one form in Rails 3.
I mean - I have a form which creates codes - which generate random - their content, string.
In controller:

```
@code = Code.new(params[:code])
characters = [('a'..'z'), ('0'..'9'), ('A'..'Z')].map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
@code.code_value = @code.code_letters + (0...8).map { characters[rand(characters.length)] }.join
```

Now I want to create codes many times clicking once, for example, I have an `input: code_quantity, :integer` then I choose quantity to 1000, and then when I click `submit`, in controller - create action should create it 1 * `code_quantity` times but it should create unique every single code like:

```
1000.times { @code = Code.new(params[:code]) }
```

`:code_value` has a validation of uniqueness.
How to do it in controller action, is it possible?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve here `I mean - I have a form which creates codes - which generate random - their content, string.` - generate random what? what's `their content`. What is generating it, the form? I can get the general idea behind this question, but can;t help you without rewording the question.

Comment: This form creates a Model - `Code` - `code_value` content is filled by controller, not in form, @code.code_value is filled by generating random 8 characters. In this form are also other inputs, like code `valid_date` which should be same in all codes, only code_value which is filled by controller should be each time unique.

Comment: Ok, thanks, much clearer now. However in your question you put some erb suggesting that code_value is part of the code. Please edit your question so it is clear that it is not in the form.

Comment: Edited - thanks for your attention and waiting for a reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the concerns - Generating a uniq random code does not seem like anything controller should be concerned with. This is strictly model related behaviour, so let's refactor it a little and move it into a model:

```
class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
  CODE_CHARS = ['a'..'z', '0'..'9', 'A'..'Z'].flat_map &:to_a

  after_initialize do
    generate_code unless code_value.present?
  end

  def self.generate_code
    code_letters + (0..8).map { CODE_CHARS.sample }.join
  end

  def generate_code
    self.code_value = self.class.generate_code
  end

end
```

Now it would be tempting to do the following in your controller:

```
@codes = Array.new(params[:code_quantity]) { Code.new(params[:code]) }
@codes.each &:save
```

It is not so easy though - it might happen that some of your models will break uniqueness validation and will not be saved as a result (quite unlikely, but there are only 218340105584896 unique combinations for 8 characters). To fix that you need:

1) Add uniqueness constraint to the database if you haven't already (uniqueness validation does not ensure the uniqueness of record - concurrency is a ...):

```
# New migration
def change
  add_index :codes, :code_value, unique: true
end
```

2) Override `save!` method:

```
class Code 
  ...
  def save!(*args)
    tries = 0;
    begin
      super
    rescue
      tries += 1
      raise if errors.any? || tries > 10
      generate_code
      retry
    end
  end
```

Now every time you tries to save the record and it will fail for any other reason than validation, it will try to regenerate the code 10 times before giving up.

Comment: Thank you a lot! One line needed small correct: `@codes = Array.new(params[:code_quantity]) { Code.new(params[:code]) }` to `@codes = Array.new(params[:code][:code_quantity].to_i) { Code.new(params[:code]) }`

Comment: use `after_initialize on: :create do`

Comment: Another alternative for code generation:
`def generate_code`
 `self.code_value = loop do`
 `random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)`
 `break random_token unless Code.exists?(code_value: random_token)`
 `end`
`end`

Comment: @mohameddiaa27 - Just a note that this still requires unique constraint and save override as it is not guaranteeing uniqueness of the code.